# How to make inner pages work after uploading wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I stuck with a issue. I've just uploaded my new wordpress site, but don't know why my inner pages are not working. I am getting 404 page not found error, my homepage is running but inner pages are not working after uploading.

Comment: have u uploaded the wordpress theme or the whole wp to your server?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setting > Permalink and choose the desired pattern, and save the changes.